# Change color buttons on Android AppBar

Tags: android

How to change the color of the buttons on the AppBar ?, in my case the back button, the default color is white

[image]

But I get mine and I want to change black to white try with accent colors and still not change me.
I am using toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/toolBarTheme" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: show you xml and java code, so ppl can help you

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/#q=change+homeasupindicator+programmatically+android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in new versions android uses material design for the backbutton , you can change the colour filter and set that as the back button

```
  final Drawable backArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    backArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(backArrow);
```